# Redshift View Casting data as Super Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, how can I cast object as a Super Type in view creation ?
for example, I want to select 1, 2, cast ((select 3,4)  AS SUPER) ;

I found this page
https://blaqfireroundup.wordpress.com/2021/05/14/working-with-the-super-type-in-amazon-redshift/ explaining how to use super type, but this does not explain how to cast super type in a view

Answer (score 0):

The JSON_PARSE() function is the easiest way to do this.  This function takes a string as an argument and as you can form this json string from any information you have in your query.  JSON_PARSE() returns a super type.

Your example doesn't makes sense as if isn't a json and doesn't map to a super.  Here's an example that might help.

```
select A, B, 
    json_parse('[' || C || ', ' || D || ']') as S
FROM (select 1 as A, 2 as B, 3 as C, 4 as D);
```